# Error only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6.

I am trying to do:

```
import numpy as np

def run_11(x):
return x+1

kk = np.arange(1, 17)

for i in range (kk):
     ind = run_11(i)
     print (i)
     print (ind)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

I couldn't figure why and how to solve it. any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you need the `range(kk)` call? Can't you just use `kk` in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `range(kk.shape[0])`:

```
for i in range(kk.shape[0]):
     ind = run_11(i)
     print (i)
     print (ind)
```

`range()` takes an integer as argument, not an NumPy array. `.shape[0]` gives you an `16`,  the length of your array.

It would be much short to do:

```
res = run_11(kk)
```

This also faster and takes advantage of NumPys vectorization abilities.

Answer (score 3):

Use `for i in kk` instead of `for i in range(kk)` because `kk` is already a range. You were trying to do `for i in range(np.arange(1, 17))` which does not make sense because range takes input in as a number, not another range.